# VSCode copying sqlite database files to root folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

so in VSCode, I opened my `Python Scripts` folder then in folder `Flet>>crud school app` I tried to run `main.py` and showed an error that I cannot connect to the database `dbone.db`, the database file was inside the `crud school app>>db` folder

in the `main.py` file I was using the code `conn = sqlite3.connect("db/dbone.db")`

then went into my `Database example` folder and ran the `courses.py` file (connected to the `courses.db` database file), it ran fine but I noticed there were no entries in the database which was odd because it had entries before, but i can add and then search the added entry

went back to the folder `Flet>>crud school app` and moved the `dbone.db` out of the `db` folder into the same path as the `main.py`, when I ran the `main.py` file the error now said it has no "user" table which it has because I can see the contents of the database with an extension in VSCode

then when I opened Windows Explorer into my `Python Scripts` folder I noticed the 3 database files at the bottom which you can see in the attached pic which had a date same as today 2/11/2024

I copied the `dbone.db` file from the `Flet>>crud school app` and overwrote the newly created `dbone.db` in the root folder, I can now connect without error when running the `main.py` in the `Flet>>crud school app` folder

So now I can assume the Python files are referencing the database files in the root folder and not the database files in their respective folders

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and how can i fix it to correctly reference to their respective database file in the same folder?

[image]